# Customizing admin ui-widget in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail, django-taggit, weblog

I use `django-taggit 0.23.0` and `wagtail 2.0.2` for a weblog app called `puput 1.0.2`.
 [Puput github repo](https://github.com/APSL/puput)
My preferred language is Persian (Farsi) in Wagtail's admin dashboard and one of my language letters is on the "comma" key of keyboard.
 So, each time I want to use that letter, tag gets submitted and I cannot add tags properly. How can I customize ui-widget in adding/editing tags in admin's dashboard? 
I also tried using these command lines in settings and overwriting its functions but yet didn't solve my problem:

> TAGGIT_TAGS_FROM_STRING = 'utils.comma_joiner' 
>   TAGGIT_TAGS_FROM_STRING = 'utils.comma_splitter'

Any solution would be a lot appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade to Wagtail 2.3. This includes a fix for the same issue on Cyrillic keyboards (where the letter б corresponds to the comma key) and should hopefully fix the problem for Persian too.

[Original bugfix](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/4761)

[Wagtail 2.3 release notes](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/releases/2.3.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but actually I'm using `puput 1.0.2` as a django app inside my project and when I update Wagtail, it gives this error:  
   `puput 1.0.2 has requirement wagtail<2.1,>=1.0, but you'll have wagtail 2.3 which is incompatible.` What should I do?

Comment: and also, when I want to makemigrations, the following error occurs:   
`The included URLconf '<module 'wagtail.search.urls' from wagtail/search/urls/__init__.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import`.

Comment: Regarding the `puput` dependency issue, you'll have to wait for them to release a newer version which works with Wagtail 2.3. There is a PR waiting https://github.com/APSL/puput/pull/181.

Comment: As for the `search.urls` issue, I imagine it happens since you upgraded to Wagtail 2.3 which removed the frontend search view https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/commit/2c8d7371b4ee6eb3520088eca23922529da852e7 so you'll have to remove `from wagtail.search import urls as wagtailsearch_urls` and `url(r'^search/', include(wagtailsearch_urls)),` from your settings.

Comment: Yes, you are actually right, I realized that last night & I extended `Puput` urls into my code base and it worked perfectly. I also created another app in my project and put those urls inside of it, but when I pushed my code to production server `(ubuntu 16.04)`, I got internal server error. I use `nginx` & `uwsgi`. @LoïcTeixeira

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to `Wagtail 2.3` solves this problem, but, another problem occurs with compatibility of `puput` with `Wagtail`, which happens because in latest version of `puput 2.0.1`, the frontend search view was deleted but, you can solve this problem by extending/changing puput urls and deleting the search view url.